# Sharepoint web part for editing list items

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I'm trying to create a web part that will enable users to edit items without ever leaving the AllItems.aspx page. The web part should have a similar functionality like the EditForm.aspx page.

I've created a simple web part with a ConnectionConsumer("Row") that successfully shows the selected ListItem but I'm trying to figure out how to programmatically create a form depending on the list with a save/update functionality.

I would appreciate a simple solution or a nudge in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible out of the box but it should be possible to use the SPGridView and the ListFieldIterator decorated with AJAX to get the things working as you wanted.

You can refer to the below items and build a control that does what you want.

1. Using [SPGridView](http://blogs.msdn.com/powlo/archive/2007/02/25/displaying-custom-data-through-sharepoint-lists-using-spgridview-and-spmenufield.aspx) in WebParts
2. Articles on [ListFieldIterator](http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/sharepoint-controls/listfielditerator/)
3. [ListFieldIterator](http://the-e.net/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=24)

Once you build it you can try sharing the code as this is a pretty common thing everyone wants and I didn't find a good implementation of this kind so far.

Comment: Thanks, the ListFieldIterator seems like the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely sounds like a nice feature. I would love it if you could put the solution on codeplex, you're choice of course.

I've had a [sneak peak on SharePoint 2010](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/2010/Sneak_Peek/Pages/default.aspx) and AJAX enabled editing is found on lots of places so I wouldn't be surprised if some kind of feature like the one you are working on will be included.

Good luck!